# How to remove cpp files from production build via webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron, webpack-4, electron-builder

I use [webpack 4](https://webpack.js.org/) and [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/) to bundle and build my Electron app. I noticed that native node modules inside the `node_modules` directory of the app`.asar` bundle still contain their C++ source files.

Is there a way to exclude certain file extensions from the build step?

Comment: normally the package owner should use the `.npmignore` file to exclude those files. You should create a Pull Request to suggest these changes.

Comment: The cpp files are meant to be published, just not packaged, so not sure `npmignore` is the right option here

Comment: Have you tried the `checkResource` filter function from the `IgnorePlugin`: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**electron-builder** can exclude files in the **files** section of your `package.json`.

> Default pattern **/* is not added to your custom if some of your patterns is not ignore (i.e. not starts with !). package.json and **/node_modules/**/* (only production dependencies will be copied) is added to your custom in any case. All default ignores are added in any case — you don’t need to repeat it if you configure own patterns.

### Example

```
"!**/node_modules/*/{CHANGELOG.md,README.md,README,readme.md,readme}",
```